# T-SQL view the table from rows to columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this Table below:

```
YEAR        QUARTER     BONUS
2013        Q1          1000       
2013        Q2          1500       
2013        Q3          1300      
2013        Q4          1500       
2014        Q1          2000       
2014        Q2          1300      
2014        Q3          1500       
2014        Q4          1300      
2015        Q1          1800       
2015        Q2          1300      
2015        Q3          1800       
2015        Q4          1800
```

I want to create a view to show as following (sort by year, bonus)

```
YEAR   BONUS    QUARTER_1    QUARTER_2    QUARTER_3
2013   1000     Q1           NULL         NULL
2013   1300     Q3           NULL         NULL
2013   1500     Q2           Q4           NULL
2014   1300     Q2           Q4           NULL
2014   1500     Q3           NULL         NULL
2014   2000     Q1           NULL         NULL
2015   1300     Q2           NULL         NULL
2015   1800     Q1           Q3           Q4
```

Comment: Why is there no `QUARTER_4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `ROW_NUMBER` and conditional aggregation:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [YEAR], BONUS ORDER BY QUARTER)
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT
    [YEAR],
    BONUS,
    QUARTER_1 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN [QUARTER] END),
    QUARTER_2 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN [QUARTER] END),
    QUARTER_3 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN [QUARTER] END),
    QUARTER_4 = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN [QUARTER] END)
FROM Cte
GROUP BY [YEAR], BONUS
ORDER BY [YEAR], BONUS;
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/461854)</kbd>

Comment: @Kenneth Glad to have been of help! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Comment: This works fine in T-SQL. It doesn't work when I create new view in MS SQL Server Studio. I want to save it in view, so that I can link it in Excel. How would I be able to achieve it?

Comment: Remove the `ORDER BY` clause since `ORDER BY` is not allowed in a `VIEW`.

Comment: Getting the error message after pasted your code in Create New View: SQL text cannot be represented in the grid pane and diagram pane.

Comment: It works great now. All I have to do is just to click continue and save it. I can link it in Excel with the result I want. Thank you very much.